# How to make a brand new WordPress blog a subdirectory of a Rails app hosted in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku

I currently have a Rails 4 app hosted on heroku under "my-app-domain.com".  My ultimate goal is to put a WordPress blog hosted elsewhere (e.g Arvixe) under "my-domain.com/blog" for SEO purposes.

Some more details:

- The blog will be brand new.
- My Rails 4 app is hosted on heroku under "my-app-domain.com"
- I've bought hosting in Arvixe for the blog and set up a dummy blog under "some-other-domain.com". I'm using Arvixe but as the blog will be brand new, I'm open to change the hosting service if needed to achieve this.

Questions:

1. How can I achieve this?
2. Do I need to set up my blog as a sub-domain "blog.my-app-domain.com" first and then use the rack-reverse-proxy gem to change it to "my-app-domain.com/blog"?
3. Do I need to purchase SSL in both Heroku and Arvixe for all my site to run under SSL?

Comment: have you found anything about this subject ? I am interested in as well. thanks

Comment: No luck for me with this.  I found something using rack reverse but it didn't actually work.